# MySQL replace query with a wildcard does not run

Tags: mysql, replace, wildcard

I have a lot of entries in the table, which start with FOO and end with BAA

like so:

```
FOO here anything 111 BAA
FOO here anything 222 BAA
FOO here anything 333 BAA
FOO here anything 444 BAA
FOO here anything 555 BAA
```

I want to remove all of this .. including the `FOO` and the `BAA`

A normal select query runs with a `LIKE 'FOO%BAA'` but does not run with a REPLACE.

Any clues as to why?

Comment: can you add the queries which you have executed.

Comment: Options for doing this kind of preg_match stuff in MySQL (at least versions older than 8.0) are extremely limited.

Comment: @Strawberry Use your noggin, you red berry!

Comment: What should happen to a string like 'hello FOO x FOO y BAA world'?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you want to remove the text beginning with, and including `FOO`, up to `BAR`, whenever both these strings occur.  It also assumes that `FOO` and `BAR` only occur once each, should they occur.  One approach is to splice out the text you don't want:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, 'FOO', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, 'BAA', -1))
WHERE col LIKE '%FOO%BAA%';
```

The demo below doesn't show the update, but it at least shows that the splicing logic works.

### Demo